# Link a Blog into scrolling text of SWF file

Tags: dynamic, flash, autofill, blogspot

I'm working on an entirely flash-based site for a client who has already been using Blogspot for his News/Homepage updates. He wants to continue updating through Blogspot, but wants the blog to automatically fill in the text box on the flash site Homepage. I'm not sure if this is possible, or how I would go about doing it.

Here is the blogspot page: 
http://atmarsamps.blogspot.com/

Here is an example of what the scrolling SWF text box will be like:
http://eloquentcreative.com/

Is this possible? Any help would be absolutely amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLLoader to load the page as text. I'm not sure of the best way to parse it though.

Maybe you can try looking for the CSS tag that is being used for the text in question and then grabbing the text in between those tags? There might be better ways to do this though.

Note, you can update values to the htmlText property of a text box, which will allow Flex to maintain some of the styles specified from the loaded page.